# How to see vimrc files used during startup

Tags: startup, vim

I've moved my vimrc file out of the home directory to pathogenize the setup, but it looks like my vim is still picking up a redundant vimrc file that I made somewhere. Is there some variable in vim that I can echo that'll show what files were used during startup?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`:scriptnames` lists all sourced script names, in the order they were first sourced.

Comment: All of these answers worked, but this was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Look for the $MYVIMRC variable:

```
:echo $MYVIMRC
```

Answer (score 2):

After starting vim, you can type

```
:set runtimepath
```

See the docs here: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'runtimepath'

I don't think @skinp's answer is necessarily sufficient. the runtimepath variable is the very definition of all places vim looks

Answer (score 1):

Additionaly, you can launch Vim with

```
$ vim --startuptime filename
```

which should write a list of loaded scripts (including vimrc) and their respective processing time to file `filename`.